# How to efficiently assign a column value based on the occurance of string in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

The objective is to assign the value in the column `GP` based on a look up table (i.e., `group_post_dict`). If the text in `GP` contain any of the string in the `lookup`, then the column `GP` will be assign based proper `lookup` and `group_` pair.

The following code demonstrate better,

```
group_post_dict = {1: {'lookup': ['pet dog', 'pet cat'], 'group_': 'pet'},
                   2: {'lookup': ['flow red', 'flow yellow'], 'group_': 'flow'},
                   3: {'lookup': ['b year', 'c year'], 'group_': 'year'}}

data_list=['pet dog', 'pet cat','flow red', 'flow yellow','b year', 'c year']
df = DataFrame ( data_list)
df.columns =['PU']


for key, value in group_post_dict.items ():
    mask_sv = df ['PU'].str.contains (
        r'\b(?:{})\b'.format ( '|'.join ( value ['lookup'] ) ) )
    df.loc [mask_sv, 'GP'] = value ['group_']
```

How, the number of loop the `for loop` need to iterate increase with the number of  `lookup` and `group_` pair.

May I know whether this code can be improved further?

p.s., sorry for the lake of better title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with flatten values of dictionary for flatten dict:

```
d= {x:v['group_'] for k, v in group_post_dict.items() for x in v['lookup']}
print (d)
{'pet dog': 'pet', 'pet cat': 'pet', 'flow red': 'flow', 
 'flow yellow': 'flow', 'b year': 'year', 'c year': 'year'}

df['GP'] = df['PU'].map(d)
 
print (df)
            PU    GP
0      pet dog   pet
1      pet cat   pet
2     flow red  flow
3  flow yellow  flow
4       b year  year
5       c year  year
```

Comment: Hi Jez,may I know what do you mean by depends of values?

Comment: @balandongiv - Not 100% sure what is limit of it, if 1k values or more, the best test it.

Comment: In your solution are lists with join, so no problem with limit, in mysolution all data are joined togetehr, so possible limit, also if large data my solution should be slowier like your, because internally more loops.

Comment: @balandongiv - now see accepting another answer, so need `df['GP'] = df['PU'].map(d)` what is faster like another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Construct dataframe from `group_post_dict`, `explode` and `map`

```
df['GP'] = df.PU.map(pd.DataFrame(group_post_dict).T
                       .explode('lookup').set_index('lookup')['group_'])

Out[158]:
            PU    GP
0      pet dog   pet
1      pet cat   pet
2     flow red  flow
3  flow yellow  flow
4       b year  year
5       c year  year
```

Comment: Performance of `explode` is worse like `d= {x:v['group_'] for k, v in group_post_dict.items() for x in v['lookup']}`